# xpath is not fetching full text which is written in "greek"

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to get the title and description of the specific product written in greek language i want the output in greek aswell. but it is not showing full title . why?

here is my scrapy code.

```
import scrapy

class FitcoupleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'fitcouple'
    allowed_domains = ['fitcouple360.gr']
    start_urls = ['https://fitcouple360.gr/product/herbalife-f1-threptika-meal-bars-sokolata/']

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.xpath(".//div[@class='content-page container']/div[contains(@class,'single-product product')]")
        
        for product in products:
            title = product.xpath("//div//div[@class='fixed-content']/h1/text()").get()
            print(title)
```

the product title is "Θρεπτικό πρωτεϊνούχο ρόφημα Herbalife Formula 1 υγιεινό γεύμα Café Latte 550g"

but i am getting output "Herbalife F1 Θρεπτικά Meal Bars σοκολάτα"

```
2022-09-27 22:49:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://fitcouple360.gr/product/herbalife-f1-threptika-meal-bars-sokolata/> (referer: None)
**Herbalife F1 Θρεπτικά Meal Bars σοκολάτα**
2022-09-27 22:49:56 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-09-27 22:49:56 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

Comment: I'm talking about title .. actual title is "Θρεπτικό πρωτεϊνούχο ρόφημα Herbalife Formula 1 υγιεινό γεύμα Café Latte 550g"   but I am getting "Herbalife F1 Θρεπτικά Meal Bars σοκολάτα"   not getting these first three words in my output "Θρεπτικό πρωτεϊνούχο ρόφημα"

Answer (score 2):

The above url contains the product title:Herbalife F1 Θρεπτικά Meal Bars σοκολάτα which is correct. If not then You have injected the another link please justify the title with link whether it is correct or not

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the part of html you get by this `xpath("//div//div[@class='fixed-content']/h1/text()")` doesn't contain this `Θρεπτικό πρωτεϊνούχο ρόφημα Herbalife Formula 1 υγιεινό γεύμα Café Latte 550g` but instead it contains this `Herbalife F1 Θρεπτικά Meal Bars σοκολάτα` 
the problem is not with title or greek language encoding
the problem is either wrong xpath or js that dynamically changes data and makes you get wrong product

Comment: no , please check it again . //div//div[@class='fixed-content']/h1/text()

Comment: F.Hoque has just checked it, maybe it's wrong link (=wrong product)